# IOUtils copy and write issues

Tags: java, client-server

I'm trying to send strings to a server from a client but it doesn't seem to be reading from the input stream.

Client

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
Socket connection = new Socket("localhost", 13)
OutputStream out = connection.getOutputStream();

while(true) {
    String message = scanner.nextLine();
    IOUtils.write(message, out, "UTF-8");
    out.flush();
}
```

Server

```
ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(localhost,13);~
Socket connection = server.accept();
InputStream in = connection.getInputStream();
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();

while(true) {
    try {
        IOUtils.copy(in, writer);
        System.out.println(writer.toString());
    } catch(IOException io) {}
}
```

It reads if I close the stream from the client's outputstream but I am trying to send multiple messages from the client to the server. Could someone please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to think that each time you call flush() at client-side, the server will know it and be able to know that this is the end of a message. That's not the case. `IOUtils.copy()` reads everything from a stream of bytes. While the stream end hasn't been reached, `copy()` won't return.

You can see streams as two sides of a long tube. If you pour 10 buckets of water in the at the end of the tube, all you'll get at the other side is a continuous flow of water.

If you need multiple separate messages, then you need to design a protocol allowing to separate messages, and read until the end of a message has been reached. It could be based on separators for example. Or you could send the length of the message followed by the message itself, to let the server know how many bytes it must read to get the next message.

Comment: The OP wants to send lines, where each line is a message. So the protocol is simple: use a PrintWriter's println method at client-side to write lines, and use a BufferedReader's readLine() method at server side to read lines. In that case, the end of a message is the EOL sent by the writer, and detected by the readLine() method. You should figure that out by yourself. That's how you'll learn.

Comment: I just updated my above comment, explaining how to do.